# Get specific columns using with() in laravel with appends fields in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my User model, I have an appends fields:

```
protected $appends = [
      'is_admin'
];
```

It will appends is_admin field in every request by using with() eager loading. However, in some scenario I don't want to return is_admin field, I am trying to use the follows:

```
$this->belongsTo('App\Models\User')
            ->select(['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
```

But it doesn't work.
Is the appends field always be appended even I use custome select field ?

Answer (score 2):

`appends` is used when the model is serialized; it 'appends' attributes to the output.

If you have a single model and you want to not have the `appends` accessors added to the serialized data, you can set them `hidden`.

Example:

```
$test = new class extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $appends = ['is_admin'];

    public function getIsAdminAttribute() {
        return rand(0, 1);
    }
};

dump($test->toArray()); // will contain 'is_admin'

$test->makeHidden('is_admin');

dump($test->toArray()); // will not contain 'is_admin'

// This can be applied to Eloquent Collections.

$model->relation->makeHidden('is_admin');
```

One way of doing it.

Comment: I try to add `$this->belongsTo('App\Models\User')->makeHidden('is_admin')`   but it will output error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::makeHidden()`

Comment: Its not a builder method, its a model method. Call it on an instance of a model or a collection of models.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this result to a variable

```
$data = $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User')->select(['id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
```

and use directly

```
$data->makeHidden("is_admin");
```

This will work for you